# How to treat error input in a dynamical angular form?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dynamic form and I want to solve the input errors. The input name is created dynamical, but I can't access it in in the error span. I assume  the angular double curly brackets executes / renders slower then the ngIf directive ? maybe that's why I don't have access to the **innerForm.inputName** (wich is 'name') ... Any suggestion ?

[Live code](https://jsfiddle.net/n82amsma/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='Main'>

  <form name='mailForm' ng-submit='submit(mailForm.$valid,form);$event.preventDefault();' novalidate>
    <ng-form name='innerForm'>
      <p>
        Name:
        <input type='text' name='{{inputName}}' ng-model='form.name' required>

        <span ng-if="innerForm.inputName.$invalid && innerForm.inputName.$touched">required</span>
      </p>
    </ng-form>

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value='Submit' ng-disabled="mailForm.$invalid" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('app',[])
 .controller('Main', function($scope){
   $scope.inputName = 'name';

   $scope.submit = function(isValid, form){
    console.log('isValid',isValid);
    console.log('form',form);
   };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer *EDIT*

Since value is changing dynamically and you never know what will be the inputName value, you still can access the scope object via selecting by key, so the span error line should go like this:

```
<span ng-if="innerForm[inputName].$invalid && innerForm[inputName].$touched">required</span>
```

---

Since you use scope value in input `name='{{inputName}}'`

And in ng-if you try to read from `innerForm.inputName`

So in your controller you should set `$scope.inputName = 'inputName';`

Else when having `$scope.inputName = 'name';` you will read the value of `name` in `innerFrom`

*EDIT*

Also consider that you have disabled the submit button, when the form in invalid, so yeah, it wont let you submit until the you fill the form and it becomes valid

Comment: I want the attribute name to have the value of "name", not "inputName", that 's whj I use angular double curly brackets. So after the page has rendered it will look something like: <input type='text' name='name' ng-model='form.name' required>

Comment: then use 'innerForm.name.$invalid' because you have set the name value/key 'name'

Comment: I don't know the input name, so I can't use hard coded like: innerForm.name.$invalid, maybe something like: innerForm.{{inputName}}.$invalid

Comment: well thats a gamechanger, try 'innerForm[inputName].$invalid', since youre acessing values in an object, by keys

Comment: yes, this works, thanks a lot sir !! edit the main response and I will vote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type='text' name='{{inputName}}' ng-model='form.name' required>
```

to

```
<input type='text' name='inputName' ng-model='form.name' required>
```

Differences: `{{inputName}}` to `inputName`

The name attribute  must be plain text. If you want to use the brackets, then set that `inputName` scope variable to 'inputName' in your controller, since you are trying to access it as `innerForm.inputName.$invalid`. The `inputName` property much match the string in the name field on the form.

Comment: I want the attribute name to have the value of "name", not "inputName", that 's whj I use angular double curly brackets. So after the page has rendered it will look something like: <input type='text' name='name' ng-model='form.name' required>